# Making Discord Mass Dm C#

Tags: discord

I'm making a self bot for discord using C# (I know its against tos) Im only doing this for knowledge

I'm using anarchys api https://ilinked1337.gitbook.io/anarchy/

```
        for (int i = 0; i < Relationships.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Relationships[i].Type == Discord.RelationshipType.Friends)
            {
                client.SendMessage()
            }
        }
```

the problem is that I'm using the send message function, and to send the message you need the user id to send it, although the relation ships function doesn return the Users Id, Is there any way I can do this I can work around this and do it

Answer (score 0):

Use the Relationships[i].User.Id and it will return the users id.

use it so:

```
 client.SendMessage(friend.User.Id, "YOURMESSAGE");
```